# speeding up R loops

Tags: r, performance, loops

I am new to this forum and a beginner in R, so sorry if my script/question is written in a confusing way.
I have weather data from approximately 130 different stations over a period of 3 years and I want to fill the gaps. Right now, I only do so for global radiation, but I have got four more variables. 
My table looks like this:

```
tbl <- read.table(text = 
"    Date.and.Time I glbRad I precipitation.mm.day I rel.hum... I wind.speed..m.s I temperature.
    1 I 2010-01-01-01 00:00:00 I 0.6 I 0.1 I 99.6 I 1 I 2.3 
    2 I 2010-01-01-01 01:00:00 I 0.6 I 0 I 99.5 I 1 I 2.2 ", 
sep = "I", header = TRUE)
```

If the gap lasts only one or two hours, I take the average of the previous and the subsequent measurements.
If the gap lasts longer than for two hours, I use the values of the nearest weather station that has complete data for the needed time period. I have got a table distanzen.csv that contains the name_i of the weather station in its first column and name_j of neighbouring weather stations. The neighbouring stations are ordered by distance.

```
neighbors <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "I",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,text = 
"name_j I name_i I distance
1 I Ainersthofen I Edelshausen I 16.303
2 I Ainersthofen I Gablingen I 19.684")
```

In general, the script works. But it is far too slow. Do you have an idea how I could speed it up? I know I should somehow get rid of the loops, but I don't quite know how to do so.
Also, if the date in the neighbouring station is completely missing (the entire row is missing), I get the  error  “argument is of length zero”. In this case, I want to pick the second nearest neighbour.

```
#reading data
file_path="F:/SkriptAktion/wetter_csv_spalten_richtig_Ortsnamen/"
setwd(file_path)
names <-list.files()
d =1
for (n in names){
  table<-read.csv(paste(file_path,n, sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  #change date format
  date <- as.POSIXlt(table$Date.and.Time, tz="utc", format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
  table$Date.and.Time<-date

  #add a column "gaps_radiation" where A) it says „ok“ if the value is not missing  B) it says „MW“ if one or two subsequent values are missing C) it says the name of the neighbouring station  if data of the neighbouring station has been used
 # write „MW“ for all missing values
  table$gaps_radiation <- character(nrow(table))
  table$gaps_radiation<-lapply(table[,"glbRad"],function(x) ifelse (x!=".", "ok", "MW"))

  #change global.radiation from character to numeric
    table$glbRad <- as.numeric(table$glbRad)

  # If the gap lasts only one or two hours, I take the average of the previous and the subsequent measurements.
  #1h gap  
  for (i in 2:(length(table$glbRad)-1)){
    if (table$gaps_radiation[i] == "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[i-1]=="ok" & table$gaps_radiation[i+1]=="ok"){
  table$glbRad[i] <- (table$glbRad[i-1]+table$[i+1])/2
}else {
  #if ((table$gaps_radiation[i] == "MW"){(table$gaps_radiation[i] == "MW"}
  table$glbRad[i] <- table$glbRad[i]
}
  }

  #2h gap

  for (i in 3:(length(table$glbRad)-1)){
    if (table$gaps_radiation[i] == "MW" 
        & table$gaps_radiation[i-1] == "MW"
        & table$gaps_radiation[i-2] == "ok"
        & table$gaps_radiation[i+1]=="ok"){
      table$glbRad[i] <- (table$glbRad[i-2]+table$glbRad[i+1])/2
  table$glbRad[i-1] <- (table$glbRad[i-2]+table$glbRad[i+1])/2
}else {table$glbRad[i] <- table$glbRad[i]
}  
  }


   # gaps in the beginning/end of table
  # 1h gap

  if (table$gaps_radiation[length(table$glbRad)]== "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[length(table$glbRad)-1]=="ok"){
table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-1]
  }else {table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)]
  }

  if (table$gaps_radiation[1]== "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[2]=="ok"){
table$glbRad[1] <- table$glbRad[2]
  }else {table$glbRad[1] <- table$glbRad[1]
  }

  # 2h gap

  if (table$gaps_radiation[length(table$glbRad)]== "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[length(table$glbRad)-1] == "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[length(table$glbRad)-2]=="ok"){
table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-2]
table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-1] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-2]
  }else {table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)]
     table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-1] <- table$glbRad[length(table$glbRad)-1]
  }

  if (table$gaps_radiation[1]== "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[2] == "MW"& table$gaps_radiation[3]=="ok"){
table$glbRad[1] <- table$glbRad[3]
table$glbRad[2] <- table$glbRad[3]
  }else {table$glbRad[1] <- table$glbRad[1]
     table$glbRad[2] <- table$glbRad[2]
  }


  #gaps > 2h

  mis_dates <- table[(is.na(table$glbRad)),"Date.and.Time"]
  if (length(mis_dates)>=1){

neighbours <- read.csv(file="F:/SkriptAktion/distanzen.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".", fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


tab1 <- read.csv(file=paste(file_path, neighbours$name_j[d*130+1], ".csv", sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tab1$Date.and.Time <- as.POSIXlt(tab1$Date.and.Time, tz="utc",format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
tab1$glbRad <- as.numeric(tab1$glbRad)

for (i in 1:length(mis_dates)){
  table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"] <- tab1[tab1$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"]
  table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i],"gaps_radiation"] <- neighbours$name_j[d*130+1]}

if (nrow(table[is.na(table$glbRad),])>0) {  
  tab1 <- read.csv(file=paste(file_path, neighbours$name_j[d*130+2], ".csv", sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  tab1$Date.and.Time <- as.POSIXlt(tab1$Date.and.Time, tz="utc",format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
  for (i in 1:length(mis_dates)){
    table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"] <- as.numeric(tab1[tab1$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"])
    table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i],"gaps_radiation"] <- neighbours$name_j[d*130+2]}
}else {table <- table}

if (nrow(table[is.na(table$glbRad),])>0) {  
  tab1 <- read.csv(file=paste(file_path, neighbours$name_j[d*130+3], ".csv", sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  tab1$Date.and.Time <- as.POSIXlt(tab1$Date.and.Time, tz="utc",format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
  for (i in 1:length(mis_dates)){
    table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"] <- tab1[tab1$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i], "glbRad"]
    table[table$Date.and.Time == mis_dates[i],"gaps_radiation"] <- neighbours$name_j[d*130+3]}
}else {write.table(table,paste("F:/SkriptAktion/Lueckenfueller_radiation/", n, sep=""),sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, na="")}

if (nrow(table[is.na(table$glbRad),])>0) {
  write.table(table,paste("F:/SkriptAktion/Lueckenfueller_radiation/", "lueckig", n, sep=""),sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, na="")
}else {table <- table}

  }else {write.table(table,paste("F:/SkriptAktion/Lueckenfueller_radiation/", n, sep=""),sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, na="")}
  d<- d+1   
}
```

Comment: Start by using `&&` instead of `&` to reduce the number of comparisons required.  See `?Logic` for more info.  And as written, the `else` does nothing, so get rid of it.

Comment: Why do you have n=names in the 7th row of your script? Also this code is too verbose and uses a lot of inbuilt functions in R like names and table which make it difficult to read the code. Can you rename the col names and make them shorter like replace "global.radiation..W.qm." with "glbRad"

Comment: sorry, n=names should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to a version of the problem, with more concise notation.

The first thing you probably want to do is load all of the tables into memory at the same time, rather than reloading the neighbor tables as you go.  The next thing I would do is create a data frame or matrix where each column contains the observations for a given station, and each row corresponds to a given time, and with missing values (i.e. `NA`) wherever there is no data.  This makes the data much easier to manipulate, rather than having it in different tables.  It is easy to do, and after you clean the observation data in this format, it is also easy to put the cleaned data back into the original tables.

I'll generate a sample dataset of this format as follows:

```
> set.seed(100)
> numID<-5
> data<-list()
> for(i in 1:numID){
+     data[[letters[i]]]<-rnorm(1000)
+     data[[i]][sample(998,200)+1]<-NA
+ }
> data<-data.frame(data)
> head(data,10)
            a          b            c           d          e
1  -0.5021924  0.1832545  0.465130835 -0.41210403 -0.8573020
2   0.1315312 -1.4173952  1.301940661          NA  0.9045634
3          NA  0.7547373 -0.427443347  0.02168948  0.8159008
4   0.8867848  0.8888487           NA -1.01383931 -1.1543267
5   0.1169713 -0.6939272 -0.540616369  0.42388204  0.4156978
6          NA -1.8599799  1.038092588 -0.75247680 -1.0199797
7          NA  0.3463114  0.714788709  2.00850576  0.2821374
8   0.7145327         NA           NA  0.81969681         NA
9          NA         NA           NA -1.14063105 -1.0967526
10 -0.3598621         NA -0.009403063          NA  0.9392961
```

So the names of the stations here are `a` `b` `c` `d` `e`.  For the sake of this explanation, I am going to represent the neighbor list data as a matrix that contains the neighbors of each station as rows, ordered by distance:

```
< nn<-c()
> for(i in 1:numID){
+   nn<-rbind(nn,sample(letters[(1:numID)[-i]]))
+ }
> rownames(nn)<-names(data)
> nn
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a "c"  "b"  "e"  "d" 
b "c"  "d"  "e"  "a" 
c "a"  "d"  "e"  "b" 
d "c"  "e"  "b"  "a" 
e "c"  "b"  "d"  "a"
```

So this means that the nearest station to `a` is `c`, followed by `b`, etc.

OK, so first thing is to fill in missing values with averages for gaps of two hours or less.  This can be done without any looping, using a call to `apply` and a helper function:

```
> fillAve<-function(x){
+   w<-which(!is.na(x))
+   d1<-w[which(diff(w)==2)]
+   d2<-w[which(diff(w)==3)]
+   x[d1+1]<-(x[d1]+x[d1+2])/2
+   x[d2+2]<-x[d2+1]<-(x[d2]+x[d2+3])/2
+   x  
+ }
> data2<-data.frame(lapply(data,fillAve))
> head(data2,10)
            a          b            c           d          e
1  -0.5021924  0.1832545  0.465130835 -0.41210403 -0.8573020
2   0.1315312 -1.4173952  1.301940661 -0.19520727  0.9045634
3   0.5091580  0.7547373 -0.427443347  0.02168948  0.8159008
4   0.8867848  0.8888487 -0.484029858 -1.01383931 -1.1543267
5   0.1169713 -0.6939272 -0.540616369  0.42388204  0.4156978
6   0.4157520 -1.8599799  1.038092588 -0.75247680 -1.0199797
7   0.4157520  0.3463114  0.714788709  2.00850576  0.2821374
8   0.7145327         NA  0.352692823  0.81969681 -0.4073076
9   0.1773353         NA  0.352692823 -1.14063105 -1.0967526
10 -0.3598621         NA -0.009403063 -0.67154451  0.9392961
```

Finally, for values that are still missing, we need to search the nearest neighbors to fill them in.  The implementation below uses two loops, but these loops only iterate over the set of locations, rather than the full dataset, so the performance hit won't be too bad.  One thing to keep in mind when trying to remove loops from R code is that the most important thing is to avoid doing the innermost loops in R, which in this case would be the loop that iterates over the individual observations.  As long as the inner loops are vectorized appropriately, using explicit loops in R at outer levels usually won't hurt performance too much, since each outer iteration will usually do enough work that the overhead of R's interpreted machinery will be small by comparison.

So this code will generate a new data frame `data3` that contains the clean data:

```
> data3<-data2
> for(i in 1:numID){  
+   x<-data3[[i]]
+   w<-which(is.na(x))
+   j<-1
+   while(length(w)>0 && j<=(numID-1)){
+     y<-data2[[nn[i,j]]]
+     x[w]<-y[w]
+       w<-which(is.na(x))
+       j<-j+1
+   }
+   data3[[i]]<-x
+ }
> head(data3,10)
            a            b            c           d          e
1  -0.5021924  0.183254452  0.465130835 -0.41210403 -0.8573020
2   0.1315312 -1.417395156  1.301940661 -0.19520727  0.9045634
3   0.5091580  0.754737319 -0.427443347  0.02168948  0.8159008
4   0.8867848  0.888848672 -0.484029858 -1.01383931 -1.1543267
5   0.1169713 -0.693927195 -0.540616369  0.42388204  0.4156978
6   0.4157520 -1.859979946  1.038092588 -0.75247680 -1.0199797
7   0.4157520  0.346311411  0.714788709  2.00850576  0.2821374
8   0.7145327  0.352692823  0.352692823  0.81969681 -0.4073076
9   0.1773353  0.352692823  0.352692823 -1.14063105 -1.0967526
10 -0.3598621 -0.009403063 -0.009403063 -0.67154451  0.9392961
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the inner loop can be vectorized fairly easily, you just need to be careful about indices because you don't want to use the first and last element.

```
i <- 2:(length(table$global.radiation..W.qm.) -1)
i <- 1 + which(table$gaps_radiation[i] == "MW" & table$gaps_radiation[i-1]=="ok" & table$gaps_radiation[i+1]=="ok")
table$global.radiation..W.qm.[i] <- (table$global.radiation..W.qm.[i-1]+table$global.radiation..W.qm.[i+1])/2
```

Comment: But is this actually faster?  Always worth running `microbenchmark`